# How to compute the cohomology $H^{*}(S^{n}, S^{k})$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $S^{k} \subset S^{n}$ be the $k$-sphere included in the $n$-sphere as the unit sphere in the first $k +1$ coordinates sitting in the unit sphere in $(n+1)$-space. Compute $H^{*}(S^{n}, S^{k})$.

Can this question be solved with Mayer-Vietoris sequence? Any hints?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just use the long exact sequence for the pair $(S^n,S^k)$ and then you're done. The only "problem" occurs if you look at $(S^n,S^{n-1}$ but then you now, that $S^n$, where you divide out the equator is the wedge of two $S^n$, which gives you the relative cohomology.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, I think I still do not do it right. May you give some more details?

Answer (score 3):

(Thorben Kastenholz advices very nice solution using long exact sequence; here is homotopic one)

the factor $S^n/S^k$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^n\cup CS^k$, and it is homotopy equivalent to $S^n\vee S^{k+1}$. (here $C$ is a cone)

so we have $H^i(S^n,S^k)=\mathbb Z$ for $i=k+1,n$, and $0$ otherwise. in case $n=k+1$ we have $H^n=\mathbb Z^2$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, I don't seem to fully understand your solution. May you please give me some for details?

Comment: @Angela step 1: $S^n/S^k$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^n\vee S^{k+1}$. step 2: $H^*(X,A)=\widetilde{H}^*(X/A)$ in case $A$ is a subcomplex of $X$

Comment: I finally put my head around these things and saw your point. Thank you so much!